# If "android.test.purchased" fails verification causing OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener to not deliver the product, will using a real SKU fix the issue?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing

As the title says, by using the sample purchase "android.test.purchased", it fails the purchase verification causing the product to not be delivered. Because of this, I can't test that the product is actually delivered without actually paying for it... so, any ways around this?